# Align a button and an EditText in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn android axml and this is very very difficult and documentation or tutorial not easy to find

I'm trying to align a button and a edittext side by side Horizontaly (more than easy to do in Winform but more than difficult in Android)

I've seen some code but none are working properly

Below I was trying to send a picture showing the result of my code but I'm not allowed yet to send picture

So I just can say that my EditText is far below the button
I need the button and EditText horizontaly aligned and with the same height
Is that possible with Android ?

And I'm also giving my axml source to try to understand what is wrong with it

Thanks for any help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ScanButton"
            android:text="Scan"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ScanText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFDCDCDC"
            android:textColor="#ff00610E"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="SCAN Product" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read about `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the gravity from the edittext. This makes it center in vertical and horizontal. That's why you see it in far below.

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

You should also put `android:layout_height="0dp"` in your second linear layout btw.